# Optimal load balancing between two hard disks. Does RAID 1 do the trick?

Tags: linux, hard-drive, raid

I am looking for a linux disk system for streaming media purposes that would do smart load balancing and minimize hard disk wear.

To illustrate my points, lets take a physical hard disk device and denote it with "A".  Then:

A() : A is idle

A(w) : A is writing

A(r) : A is reading

A(w,r): A is both writing and reading

A(r) => B(w) : A is copying data to B

Now, let's have two physical devices A and B, RAIDed into the same logical volume.

(a) The system is up-to-date and idle.  Same data resides in both volumes A and B, so:

A(), B()

(b) The system starts writing new data, while at the same time, someone is requesting old data, so it goes into the state ..

A(w), B(r)

(c) Now the operations have stopped, and the system starts replicating the data from A to B in order to have the same data in both A and B:

A(r) => B(w)

Now, my question is, does RAID 1 operate this way, i.e. like described in (a)-(c), or does it just, when writing and reading simultaneously:

A(w,r), B(w,r)

Is there any disk/file-system that would work in the way described in (a-c) ?

I guess RAID 1 might have configurable parameters that would achieve (a-c)..?

Comment: @tyson what is being asked is a reasonable question for raid 1, for raid 0 you get raw performance but none of the benefits of redundancy, with an intelligent caching raid 1 controller you could potentially be writing to one disk while reading the other, thus reducing latency and contention slightly.

Comment: from "man mdadm" I found the "--write-mostly" switch but I am not sure if it does what I want .. a "--read-mostly" if such switch would exist with "--write-mostly" would certainly do the trick ..!

Comment: Are you sure you want this behaviour? In state (b) your array is now out of sync and will remain that way until the read op completes. That's either going to degrade your writes (if your controller doesn't report write completion til it hits both disk) or it's going to open you up to a pretty ugly failure mode if disk A fails before B catches up.